# VSTO in VBA: AddIn.Object returns Nothing (null) sometimes

Tags: c#, vba, .net-3.5, vsto, excel-2007

Given:

- A VSTO Add-In
- An `override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()` which returns an instance of a class which is called `Facade` in my scenario.
- A VBA macro in Excel 2007 which accesses the `AddIn.Object` to get the Facade and uses it.
- A plenty of times where this works perfectly fine.
- **A couple of times where out of the blue, this doesn't seem to work.**

**Update: Turns out that it's a particular user that has the problem. She has it all the time, others never have it (? never say "never")**

In this "couple of times" I get

> Error: Object variable or With block variable not set

at the line of code which tries to access a property of `Facade`. In short I can tell you that the code in `RequestComAddInAutomationService()` doesn't have any error-prone magic in it, and the VBA code to access the add-in has been taken from the web and looks fine, too. The longer version is yet to come, for those who'll take the time to read it :-)

**Question: Does anyone have a clue why this can happen? Is it an Excel issue?**

---

Details as promised:

MyAddIn.cs:

```
public partial class MyAddIn
{
    public Facade Facade { get; private set; }

    protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
    {
        if (this.Facade == null)
            this.Facade = new Facade(Controller.Instance);

        return this.Facade;
    }
}
```

Facade.cs:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("1972781C-A71A-48cd-9675-AE47EACE95E8")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IFacade
{
    // some methods
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Facade : IFacade
{
    private Controller Controller { get; set; }

    public Facade(Controller controller)
    {
        this.Controller = controller;
    }
}
```

`Facade` has some methods but not a single field.

Controller.cs:

```
public class Controller
{
    private static Controller instance = null;
    public static Controller Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null) instance = new Controller();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private Controller() { }
}
```

`Controller` has some private fields. Since the fields assignments are executed on creation, I reviewed them. Most of them are not initialized at all, or they are set to `null`, so the constructor does virtually nothing.

The VBA code:

```
Dim addin As Office.COMAddIn
Dim automationObject As Object

Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("My AddIn")
Set automationObject = addin.Object

Dim oResult As Object
Set oResult = automationObject.SomeMethodThatReturnsAnObject()
```

The last line is where the error happens. Although the method called returns an object, I am pretty sure that it cannot be the source of the error: If the reference returned was `null`, then the statement would simply evaluate to `Set oResult = Nothing` which is still valid. VBA rather throws this type of error whenever a method is executed on an reference that is `Nothing`, which is `automationObject` in my case.

On the other hand, if the add-in wasn't there at all, the `Application.COMAddIns(...)` would raise an *index out of bounds* error, I've seen that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that Excel disabled the COM add-in. This is known to sometimes happen silently, without Excel complaining about anything.

So, since the add-in was registered with excel, the following line succeeded:

```
Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("My AddIn")
```

But since it was disabled, the object was not created and

```
Set automationObject = addin.Object
```

resulted in `Nothing`.

Comment: This "answer" says "excel disabled the COM add-in / known to sometimes happen silently", then explains that this explains the symptoms.  But, it doesn't explain anything about how to prevent or work around this problem.

Comment: @TonyD: You're right there - but this is out of the scope of this question. The question was only how it could happen. The reason turned out to be that the add-in was disabled. Asking why Excel could conceivably disable an add-in opens a whole new space of possible answers...

Answer (score 3):

Working most of the time and failing sometimes looks like a race-condition. Andrew Whitechapel has written about a race condition related to `RequestComAddInAutomationService`<sup>1</sup>:

> **[COMAddIns Race Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andreww/comaddins-race-condition)**

Although he says that race conditions should not be a problem with in-process VBA macros, it could be that the problem might happen in your specific scenario.

Try the suggested workaround and loop until your `Addin.Object` is valid (C# code, similar in VBA):

```
while (utils == null)
{
    utils = (ComServiceOleMarshal.IAddinUtilities)addin.Object;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}    
utils.DoSomething();
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>There's lots of useful information on his blog for the things you are doing, so don't miss the related articles.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I've read it. Unfortunately it seems not to apply to my case: I *do* call the add-in from VBA. I've now added the details to my question. If you could spot a race condition in that code, I'd be happy. Though it seems more like there isn't any... (of course, the retry-several-times trick might still do it)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, often but not always, so I can't say for certain but the thing that seemed to fix it was going to Project / Application / Assembly Information... and checking Make assembly COM-Visible, then creating the object (in Excel VBA) with:

```
Set automationObject = CreateObject("PlugInDllName.PlugInClass")
```

No problems since - fingers crossed.