# How do I make my GUID visible for a VSTO Add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, guid, outlook-addin

I've tried adding the following code to the beginning of my add-in code as such:

```
Namespace NS
    [Guid("211B3945-E2AE-48DD-8A9A-77ADB40EC6D5")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public partial class Classname
    {
```

but it doesn't appear when I list the COMAddins (the name does, but not the GUID).

I've also tried setting it in my compile settings under Assembly information with no luck.

BTW - the issue I'm trying to resolve is seeing if a COM Addin is loaded by searching for its GUID.  The Addin description shows up when I check the list of ComAddIns, but the GUID still shows zeroes no matter how I follow these directions.  I'm trying to see what's visible by using the following code:

```
olApp = this.Application;
Office.COMAddIns CAIs = olApp.COMAddIns;
foreach (Office.COMAddIn CAI in CAIs)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(CAI.Description);
    sb.AppendLine(CAI.Guid);
    sb.AppendLine("****");
    Debug.Print(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Perhaps http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/667414/ can help you, it mentions retrieving the GUID with VBA.

Comment: I got the code working, but I don't see where it returns the GUID

Comment: Even when I specifically try to print the GUID for this item, I still get all zeroes.

Comment: I'll see if I can get it working this weekend.

Comment: Thanks, Stijn.  I can shoot you my e-mail if you'd like and we can post the final results up here as an answer (if it works ;))

Comment: Larry, have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem right now. I can identify the add in by its name but would prefer the guid witch is always 00000000-0000-...

Comment: Did anyone found this answer about 00000000-000

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things missing here to expose COM, including overriding `RequestComAddInAutomationService` and setting `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]`

See the following items:

1. [VSTO Add-ins, COMAddIns and RequestComAddInAutomationService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice.aspx)
2. [VSTO in VBA: AddIn.Object returns Nothing (null) sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145717/vsto-in-vba-addin-object-returns-nothing-null-sometimes)

Comment: I have code similar to this that I gleaned from an old posting by Ken Slovak, but I'm still getting all zeroes.  I can post my code if that will help, but it's multiple files.

Comment: BTW - the issue I'm trying to resolve is seeing if a COM Addin is loaded by searching for its GUID.  The Addin description shows up when I check the list of ComAddIns, but the GUID still shows zeroes no matter how I follow these directions